# MySQL query combine rows

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have table structure like this

```
id | fieldno | fieldvalue Id|taxper|value
1  | 10      |            2 |    0 | 100    
1  | 20      |            2 |    5 | 110 
1  | 30      |            2 |    10| 200  
1  | 40      |
```

Desired output like

```
id   0%  5%   10 %
1    100 110  200
```

I want to combine rows into different columns

Comment: I think you will need dynamic SQL for this, since the `taxper` values may be unknown (and variable) each time you run the query.

Comment: What if `taxper` has a lot of values?

Comment: A more common use case would be that your want to show quartiles (25% increments) or quantiles (20% increments).  If this is OK with you, then a simple pivot query should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

For current sample data, it's simple pivot case:

```
select
    id,
    max(if(taxper=0, value, null)) as `0%`,
    max(if(taxper=5, value, null)) as `5%`,
    max(if(taxper=10, value, null)) as `10%`
from table1
group by id
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b55b2/1)

If there are a lot of values for `taxper`, then you may need this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(taxper = ''',
      taxper,
      ''', value, NULL)) AS `',
      taxper, '%`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Table1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', @sql, ' FROM Table1 GROUP BY id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b55b2/4)